# WP Customer Reviews Pagination and Form Submit only works when logged in to admin

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Whenever I log out of `WordPress Admin Area` and do a form submit or try to paginate the page throws a `An unknown error has occurred. E01`.

`Pagination` does not work at all. The form submit works but still throws an error.

When I am logged in, the plugin works perfectly. I am using a custom theme.

Plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-customer-reviews/

Issue Page: http://dev.westshorehome.com/customer-testimonials/

Edit: I found out when I add the below code to my `wp-config.php` the page does not throw the error:

```
// Enable WP_DEBUG mode
define('WP_DEBUG', true);

// Disable display of errors and warnings
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
@ini_set('display_errors',0);
```

Comment: Check your network console, you are getting PHP errors: `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /homepages/24/d602617292/htdocs/dev/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php on line 1445` **and also** `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /homepages/24/d602617292/htdocs/dev/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php:1445) in /homepages/24/d602617292/htdocs/dev/wp-content/plugins/wp-customer-reviews/wp-cu‌​stomer-reviews-3.php on line 815`

Comment: You would see this in your `error_log` as well

Comment: improved the readability of question and fixed some grammatical mistake

Comment: I saw that in my debug.log. I haven't changed anything in the `wp-admin` folder. I have a temporary fix I just don't know if it is good practice. when i add to my functions `define('WP_DEBUG', true);define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false); @ini_set('display_errors',0);` there is no more errors. Is it ok to have this running on  a live site?

Comment: Not my functions my `wp-config.php`